# Matlab: find multiple elements in an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, modulo

I want to find multiple elements of a value in an array in Matlab code.
I found the function mod and find, but these return the indices of elements and 
not the elements. Moreover, I wrote the following code:

```
x=[1 2 3 4];
if (mod(x,2)==0)
a=x;
end
```

but this does not work. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: note that you are not using indexes. `a=x` copies the whole `x` to `a`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you what to find all multiples of 2 (or any number), you can achieve this using :

```
a = x( mod(x,2) == 0 ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `a = x`, `x` is still `x=[1 2 3 4]` regardless if `(mod(x,2)==0)` is true or false;
you can assign a value to `(mod(x,2)==0)`, e.g. `val = (mod(x,2)==0)`, then append/add this value to a new array.

Answer (score 0):

Given a vector `numberList = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];` and a number `number = 2;` you can find indices (position in a vector) of the numbers in the `numberList` that are a multiple of *number* using `indices = find(mod(numberList, number) ==0);`.

If necessary you may display a list of this multiples calling: `multiples = numberList(indices)`.

```
multiples =

     2     4     6
```